# Unable to change the value of a button input field when the id contains a period character

Tags: jquery, button, input

I am unable to change the value of a button using jQuery when the id of a button input field, contains the '.' period character.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>  
</head>

<body>
Hello this is a JQuery test page.
<input id="my.button" type="button" value="" />

    <script type="text/Javascript">     
        $( "#my.button" ).val("Check Available");
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

However, if I replace '.' with '_', it works fine. I am using jQuery 1.3.2 (but I see this behavior with jQuery 1.7.1 also) and am running this html on Firefox 21.0

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>  
</head>

<body>
Hello this is a JQuery test page.
<input id="my_button" type="button" value="" />

    <script type="text/Javascript">     
        $( "#my_button" ).val("Check Available");
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Am I doing something wrong in the first code snippet, or is this a bug ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape that period with `\\`

```
$( "#my\\.button" ).val("Check Available");
```

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as 
>   !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must
>   be escaped with with two backslashes:`\`. For example, an element with
>   id="foo.bar", can use the selector `$("#foo\\.bar")`

- http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Thanks a ton! That worked. However if I have a span element, then the selection seems to work without escaping the '.' (when calling the html() function). Is a span element different in any way ?

Comment: No, their is nothing different with span , try it here `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/E3kZy/